# python mocking a function call during module import in test file

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest.mock

I'm trying to mock a function call that executes when a module is imported, below is the sample of the issue that I'm having

`app/module.py`

```
    from util import get_param 

    PARAM = get_param('param_name')
    class sample():
         def run_sample(self):
             print(PARAM)
```

`app/tests/test_module.py`

```
from app import module
import unittest

class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('app.module.get_param')
    def test_run_sample(self, mock_get_param):
        test_obj = module.sample()
        test_obj.run_sample()
```

This doesn't work and it calls the original get_param method instead of mocking it.

Answer (score 1):

I had recently been in this situation, the solution I went with was a bit hacky and involved modifying the internal module cache.

```py
#define mocked symbol
get_param = Mock()

class TestSample:

    @pytest.fixture
    def import_time_mock(self):
      # Trick python into thinking current test-file is target module
      orig = sys.modules["app.module"]
      sys.modules["app.module"] = sys.modules[__name__]

      nonlocal get_param 
      yield get_param

      # Restore modules cache
      sys.modules["app.module"] = orig

    def test_run_sample(self, import_time_mock):
        from app import module

        test_obj = module.sample()
        test_obj.run_sample()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your mock path is correct, but you've already imported the module in your test. So, when your test is instantiated, this `get_param` function has already been called. For this mock to work, you need to move your import statement into the test.